# Population count of rightmost n integers

Tags: data-structures, haskell, hash, bit-manipulation

I'm implementing [Bagwell's Ideal Hash  Trie](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/papers/idealhashtrees.pdf) in Haskell.  To find an element in a sub-trie, he says to do the following:

> Finding the arc for a symbol s,
>   requires ﬁnding its corresponding bit
>   in the bit map and then counting the
>   one bits below it in the map to
>   compute an index into the ordered
>   sub-trie.

What is the best way to do this?  It sounds like the most straightforward way of doing this is to [select the bits below that bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798191/extracting-rightmost-n-bits-of-an-integer) and do a population count on the resulting number.  Is there a faster or better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In particular, mask and popcount can be made to be quite efficient. Here is what the Clojure implementation does:

```
static int mask(int hash, int shift){
    //return ((hash << shift) >>> 27);// & 0x01f;
    return (hash >>> shift) & 0x01f;
}
```

...

```
static int bitpos(int hash, int shift){
    return 1 << mask(hash, shift);
}

final int index(int bit){
    return Integer.bitCount(bitmap & (bit - 1));
}
```

...

```
public INode assoc(int levelShift, int hash, Object key, Object val, Box addedLeaf){
    int bit = bitpos(hash, shift);
    int idx = index(bit);
    if((bitmap & bit) != 0)
```

Here is what I did in [my implementation in Haskell](http://github.com/ezyang/hamt):

```
type Key    = Word
type Bitmap = Word
type Shift  = Int
type Subkey = Int -- we need to use this to do shifts, so an Int it is

-- These architecture dependent constants

bitsPerSubkey :: Int
bitsPerSubkey = floor . logBase 2 . fromIntegral . bitSize $ (undefined :: Word)

subkeyMask :: Bitmap
subkeyMask = 1 `shiftL` bitsPerSubkey - 1

maskIndex :: Bitmap -> Bitmap -> Int
maskIndex b m = popCount (b .&. (m - 1))

mask :: Key -> Shift -> Bitmap
mask k s = shiftL 1 (subkey k s)

{-# INLINE subkey #-}
subkey :: Key -> Shift -> Int
subkey k s = fromIntegral $ shiftR k s .&. subkeyMask
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that more recent versions of clojure seem to not use this anymore.  They seem to just use the subkey as the index into the array.

Comment: Oh, it must have changed since the last time I updated my clojure checkout. Time to look...