# Error: Getting an extra digit in bitwise operation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to do a one dimensional Convay's game of life program, but the program keep on generating an extra digit everytime a generation is passed. Code:

```
int generation=IntegerparseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
long cells=Long.parseLong(input1, 2);
for(int i=0;i<generation;i++)//Assume 
{
    long newa=cells>>1;
    long newb=cells<<1;
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(newb));//For testing purpose
    cells=newa^newb;
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(cells));//For testing purpose
}
```

With input like

```
3
01011
```

(3 generations)
I am getting output like this

```
10110
10011
100110
101111
1011110
1001001
```

The desired output would be

```
10110
00011
00110
10111
01111
01011
```

Edit: After changing the testing code to:

```
 for(int i=0;i<generation;i++)
       {
           long newa=cells>>1;
           long newb=cells<<1;
           System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(newb));
           System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(newa));
           cells=newa^newb;
           System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(cells));//For testing purpose
       }
```

The output is:

```
10110
101
10011
100110
1001
101111
1011110
10111
1001001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew said, a left shift always produces an extra digit. This is actually a correct implementation, since the Conway's game of life takes place in an infinite universe. However, if you want to limit the size of the universe, you need to keep only the N rightmost digits of each generation, where N is the size of your universe.

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2798211/2626593), the N rightmost digits of an inteker K can be obtained with the operation `K&((1<<N)-1)`

Full working example:

```
public class ConwaysGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numGenerations = 10;

        // Size of the "universe"
        int universeSize = 12;

        // Initial value
        long cells = 29;

        for(int i=0;i<numGenerations;i++) {

            // Calculate new generation
            long newa=cells>>1;
            long newb=cells<<1;
            cells=newa^newb;

            // Limit the result to the size of the universe
            cells = rightMostBits(cells, universeSize);

            // Output to console
            System.out.println(
                    leftPadZeros(
                        Long.toBinaryString(cells), universeSize
                    )
                );

        }   
    }

    private static long rightMostBits(long data, int numBits){
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798191/extracting-rightmost-n-bits-of-an-integer
        return data & ((1<<numBits)-1);
    }

    private static String leftPadZeros(String str, int len){
        int numzeros = Math.max(len - str.length(), 0);
        return new String(new char[numzeros]).replace("\0", "0") + str;
    }
}
```

output:

```
000000110100
000001110010
000011011101
000111010100
001101000010
011100100101
110111011000
110101011100
110000010110
111000100111
```

Answer (score 1):

Say cells is `0111`. Look at what happens when you go through an iteration:

```
cells       = 0111
newa        = 0011
newb        = 1110
newa ^ newb = 1101
```

Left shifting a number always produces an extra digit and since you are doing an `XOR` with the same right shifted number the extra digit will always stay.

Comment: Why would newb be 1000? Wouldn't it be 1110?

Comment: Whoops! You're right, I corrected my answer. There will still be an extra digit however unless cells is 0.

Comment: Are there anyway to cap it at a certain number?

Comment: Yup, the modulo (`%`) operator. If you wanted to cap a number at 4 digits you would mod by `10000`; `10001 % 10000 == 0001`.